# How to get reference of iFrame from its caller in parent window

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have javascript module like below in my main page.

```
var LX = (function () {
    this.print_msg(divID){
        document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML = "some computed message";
        //above line throw error : TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
    }
    // some others functions
    retrun this;

})();
```

There are many **iframes** dynamically created in this page.
code in all iFrame as below

```
<div id="msgDiv"></div>
<script>
LX = parent.LX ;
LX.print_msg("msgDiv");
</script>
```

my problem is
**How to get reference of iFrame from its caller in parent window ??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the msgDiv is in the iframe, you need to pass window too. For example 
`LX.print_msg(window,"msgDiv");` 
and use

`this.print_msg(win,divID){
   win.document.getElementById(divID).innerHTML = "some computed message";`

Comment: is there any way i can get reference without passing **win**  argument ?